# Programmatically Modifying Xlam References

Tags: vba

I would like to add/modify references of xlsm/xlam files programmatically. So far, I have this code

```
Dim xBook As Workbook
Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject

Set xBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:\Desktop\testFileForReferenceAdding.xlsm", ReadOnly:=False)
Set vbProj = xBook.VBProject

vbProj.References.AddFromFile ("D:\Desktop\libs\xlam\libError.xlam")

xBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Set xBook = Nothing
```

The problem is that even though I can see the `libError.xlam` being added to the `xBook` in the Project Explorer, the added Reference to `libError.xlam` does not survive closing the book - when I reopen the same workbook, the reference is gone. How can I make the reference persistent?

**EDIT**
This code, however, works as expected

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile ("D:\Desktop\libs\xlam\libError.xlam")
  ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I would like to change references of other xlsm files, not just ThisWorkBook.

**EDIT2**
After a half a day of fiddling, the conclusions is: the code works for adding xlam references to **xlam** files, does **not** work for adding xlam references to **xlsm** files. Why this is so remains a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

XLAM files are opened in read-only format. While you may be able to add a reference thereto, you cannot "Save" the file in that state. You can arguably save it as a new file, kill the old file, rename it, etc. but that is kind of cumbersome....

Solution is to add references **before** you save as XLAM/compiled format, and/or use late-binding so that you don't *need* references in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for a comment. Even when I call xBook.SaveAs(SomeOtherName) the file gets saved, however without the reference to libError.xlam - is this the expected behavior? The second thing, my xlams contain code used throughout other xlsm applications (e.g. array operations, etc), not custom objects, hence late binding would not help.

Comment: Haven't tested enough to know for sure but from experience on PowerPoint addins a PPAM is a compiled file, you can't save any changes to it! That may be the case? XLAM may be different and not as restricted as the PPAM but I'm not sure. Try saving back down to an XLSM, then adding the references manually, then saving? It is maybe not an ideal process, but might give you some insight to help narrow down the problem.

Comment: But David, I am adding a reference to a xlsm file!